# JavaScript executions fill up PermSpace

Tags: garbage-collection, classloader, serverside-javascript, dynamic-class-loaders

I am working on a server side java application, that converts HL7 messages to Java objects using JavaScript. We chose JavaScript for this, because it was easy to deploy in the production system, without down time.

However, we now have the problem that the 30.000 daily executions of the JavaScript's seems to generate a lot of class garbage in the VM's PermSpace. This results in some unattractive stop-the-world garbage collections.

Do any of you know of a way to avoid generating a lot of class objects, when executing JavaScript?

Any other advice is also welcome.  

We are running on an IBM WebSpere 6.1 appserver with java 1.5. The JavaScript engine is SJP-1.0 (Mozilla Rhino).

Regards
Søren

Comment: Still have not figured out, how to solve the problem. However we are now moving to JBoss AS7, where we cannot reproduce the problem.